# operation is not implemented"

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

So I am working on a vb. net program which has a BindingNavigator.

The BindingNavigator has a save button that is supposed to save the data after adding or deleting anything from DataGridView. whenever I hit Save it tells me that The method or operation is not implemented.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the code I have for the save button:

```
Private Sub ToolStripSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripSave.Click
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.EmployeeBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.UpdateAll(Me.Test5DataSet)
        Me.EmployeeBindingNavigator.MoveLastItem = Me.BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem
        Me.EmployeeBindingNavigator.MoveNextItem = Me.BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem
        Me.EmployeeBindingNavigator.MoveFirstItem = Me.BindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem
        Me.EmployeeBindingNavigator.MovePreviousItem = Me.BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem
        Me.EmployeeBindingNavigator.AddNewItem = Me.BindingNavigatorAddNewItem
        Me.BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Enabled = True
        Me.BindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Enabled = True
        Me.BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Enabled = True
        Me.BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Enabled = True
        Me.BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Enabled = True
        Me.ToolStripReload.Enabled = True
        Me.ToolStripList.Enabled = True
        Me.ToolStripExit.Enabled = True
    Catch exception As System.Exception
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception)
        Interaction.MsgBox(exception.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, Nothing)
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the event handler being executed or is the exception generated within the `BindingNavigator`? If it's the former, what line is the exception thrown on? Where an exception is thrown is ALWAYS relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the `Throw New NotImplementedException`

The other possible problem could be that you try to call a method that is actually not available for this object.
I got this problem by using a `IQueryable`, which was not executed (even it has the matching type for the method)

Answer (score 0):

The method or operation is not implemented

Everything works fine for datagrid loading as well as for `Delete`, and `Insert`.

Already in the update apparently works normally, but when checking the oracle database, I found that there was no update. At this time I looked for `COMMIT ()`, I received the following message:

> The method or operation is not implemented after commit: Throw New
>   NotImplementedException